# Mouse.captured windows phone equivalent

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, mvvm, focus

I have a MVVM build application, for Windows Phone 8. I have read a bit about it, and found that on WPF you normally use

```
     Mouse.Capture();
```

But this is not possible on Windows Phone 8. Instead I used `ManipulationStartedEventArgs`. Where I was able to find

```
     ManipulationContainer.CaptureMouse();
```

Firstly is this the same function as:

```
     Mouse.Capture();
```

What I understand is that they bind to a `UIElement`, which the user chose ?

**Second Part**

When the mouse has been captured, normally you can invoke:

```
     Mouse.Captured
```

To see if the mouse is captured to a `UIElement`. But I have not been able to find the same method inside `ManipulationDeltaEventArgs` or `ManipulationCompletedEventArgs`.

Can you tell me how this is done in Windows Phone, and how to release the mouse again.

Comment: The concept of a "mouse" is an legacy one in a touch screen environment such as a smart phone. What is the scenario that you are trying to achieve, or problem that you are facing?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts I want to make sure that when a UIElement is chosen the moves are locked to this. The Idea for this is I have alot of UIElements that I want to enable scale and rotate. So when a user clicks the element all gestures on the screen after is locked to that.
Maybe It is because I'm not so knowledgeable of how to use pinch and  two finger actions for rotating. If you have best practices I would appreciate it alot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i did was to tap into the manipulation events and make logic there to ensure movement